# difference between predicted and learned tfidf weights tfidfVectorizer sklearn

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, tf-idf

Can someone explain the difference between TFIDF (sklearn) weights obtained by two methods, given an unseen document:

1. To get the weights from the `vocabulary_` attribute of the fitted model:

   ```
   >>> [vectorizer_.idf_[vectorizer_.vocabulary_[word]] for word in 'pancho villa saved mexico'.split()] 
   [10.453599686138697, 7.0510239445064196, 5.9265028838483307, 5.5037398873086669]
   ```
2. To get the weights by using the `transform()` method of the fitted vectorizer:

   ```
   >>> new=vectorizer_.transform(['pancho villa saved mexico.']).toarray()
   >>> new[new>0]
   array([ 0.3673986 ,  0.6978233 ,  0.39561987,  0.47068655])
   ```

I can see also the magnitudes are very different and probably they are showing completely different patterns giving completely different information about the unseen document. Thanks for the feedback on this concern also.

Comment: Can you provide the input that you fitted your `TfidfVectorizer` on? Also, note that the top one is only indexing `vectorizer_.idf_`, while the second gives the tf-idf weighted matrix—it incorporates term frequency.

Comment: Also the `l2` norm.